# Grails / Tomcat: Database connections get stuck in sleep state

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails

I have a Grails application running under Tomcat 7 and am having problems managing MySQL connections.

The problem is that each new request to the application (i.e., a page load) is creating a new MySQL connection, and these connections are not closing. Instead, they stay in a SLEEP state until the MySQL server finally refuses to accept more connections. Therefore, simply by reloading individual pages on the site at a fast rate, one can create numerous database connections.

So it seems that my connection pool isn't closing the connections with MySQL fast enough. There are a number of configuration settings for the connection pool, but I'm not sure what needs to be tuned to avoid this problem.

Here is the configuration from my context.xml file:

```
        <Resource name="jdbc/Production" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100"
            maxIdle="30"
            maxWait="10000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="1800000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
            numTestsPerEvictionRun="3"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            logAbandoned="true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            username=""
            password=""
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Production"
    />
```

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define a connection pool.

Add following code to the context.xml(it seems to be a JNDI data source):

```
pooled = "true"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

If you haven't put JDBC Pool in to your dependency configuration, add following to the `plugins` closure in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":jdbc-pool:1.0.9.3"
```

You may use other connection pools, but JDBC Pool will be my recommendation.

Comment: I tried adding the JDBC Pool plugin as you suggested. However, I still see the same behavior, with multiple MySQL connections being created when any page on the site is refreshed very quickly.

The connections do eventually go away, but only after the load on the server has increased so high as to make it unusable.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can debug this behavior?